# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'taming'

Tags: python

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-2683ccd40dcb> in <module>
     16 from omegaconf import OmegaConf
     17 from PIL import Image
---> 18 from taming.models import cond_transformer, vqgan
     19 import taming.modules
     20 import torch

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'taming'
```

I've tried everything can you please help me? I've tried putting it in the same folder and stuff so please help!

[image: 1]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
pip install taming-transformers
```

Answer (score 12):

It also may help:

```
pip install taming-transformers-rom1504
```